# Create a Color Picker, similar to Photoshop's, using Javascript and HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, graphics

I am not at all versed in Computer Graphics and am in need of creating a color picker as a javascript tool to embed in an HTML page.

First, and looking at Photoshop's one, i thought of the RGB palette as a three-dimensional matrix. My first attempt envolved:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var rgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        rgCanvas.width = 256;
        rgCanvas.height = 256;
        rgCanvas.style.border = '3px solid black';
        for (g = 0; g < 256; g++){
            for (r = 0; r < 256; r++){
                var context = rgCanvas.getContext('2d');
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(r,g);
                context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', 0)';
                context.lineTo(r+1,g+1);
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
            }
        }

        var bCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        bCanvas.width = 20;
        bCanvas.height = 256;
        bCanvas.style.border = '3px solid black';       
        for (b = 0; b < 256; b++){
            var context = bCanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0,b);
            context.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + 0 + ', ' + 0 + ', ' + b + ')';
            context.lineTo(20, b);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
        }

        document.body.appendChild(rgCanvas);
        document.body.appendChild(bCanvas);
    </script>
```

this results in something like
 [image: 3D RGB color map]

My thought is this is too linear, comparing to the ones i see in Photoshop and on the web.
I would like to know the logic behind the color mapping in a picker like this:
[image: photoshop color picker]

I don't really need the algorythms itself, i'm mainly trying to understand the logic.

Thanks

Comment: thanks, but i'm trying to build one from scratch for two reasons: for the fun of it and using only canvas, independent from imgs

Comment: "for the fun of it" part is definitely worth it! :) I'd probably do it too. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I implemented a canvas based color picker once. I did it because most color picker that I found on the web used too many static images and I didn't want to cause extra requests.

The color generation is based on a [10K javascript entry](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/how_i_built_a_canvas_color_picker) that I found. I Just fixed some bugs and did some refactoring on the code.

All you have to do is to include a `<input type="color-picker" />` in your code and call the `PICKER.bind_inputs()` after the DOM is loaded.

Here is a jsFiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mShET/1/

Bear in mind that The HTML5 specification [already supports](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.color.html) a color picker form input. But currently, only Opera has implemented it.

Comment: i like yours, but i'm really trying to understand how this RGB + HSB works.

Comment: My bad, I really missed your question. Have you already checked the Wikipedia article on HSV? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question about the logic behind the Photoshop picker: it looks like the colour picker is based on the HSB colour space. The hue (H) is picked by the vertical slider on the right, the saturation (S) is picked by the horizontal axis of the colour picker area, and the brightness(B) is picked by the vertical axis of the colour picker area.

To quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV):

> The original purpose of HSL and HSV and similar models, and their most common current application, is in color selection tools. At their simplest, some such color pickers provide three sliders, one for each attribute. Most, however, show a two-dimensional slice through the model, along with a slider controlling which particular slice is shown.

Comment: Even ignoring my lack of knowledge in this area, there is something missing there, in my opinion. If you control HxSxB in that three-dimensional way, where does RxGxB come into play?

Comment: I can't comment on why they've done it that way, I just went into Photoshop and moved the picker up and down, side to side and then moved the slider on the right. It definitely directly controls the HSB colour space. I guess they just convert the colour picked into all the other colour spaces displayed, and conversely, convert any colours entered by hand back into HSB before altering the colour picker to show the colour.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what i'm trying to understand, so i can build an algorythm from that knowledge

Answer (score 2):

See Here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/GXuqb/2/

Using `ColorPicker`

See the code for it here: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 0):

I created a JavaScript project, "MasterColorPicker", that has 4 different canvas based color-pickers.  It took me several months of both reading Wikipedia articles on "Color Wheel" as well as "HSB" and "HSL" and "RGB", and also working with the algorithms directly as I built each color-picker from scratch.  One thing I focused on in this project is bringing the LOGIC of these color-spaces into an easy-to-understand and use format.  My hope is that just using the project will help you to understand each color-space.  As far as mapping from one space to another, for example, the relationship between RGB and HSL, you must really expand your 3D imagination to begin that.  That is where I hope this project can help.  But really, don't bang your head against the wall for years trying to figure out these algorithms.  Besides Wikipedia, see:

http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH

All the formulas you can digest.  EXCEPT:  Wikipedia talks about "Chroma" in one of their articles and says not to confuse it with "saturation".  My MasterColorPicker project adds another color-space, hue-chroma-gray (HCG), and the source code for this project documents the formulas for converting between HCG and RGB.  With HCG, you can find the organization of the "Web-Safe" colors, and the "RainbowMeistro Color-Picker" in the project will give you a clear visualization of that color-space.  You can try the project and download the JavaScript/HTML files to use it on your own system (open-source and free) from here:

http://softmoon-webware.com/MasterColorPicker_instructions.php

Peace!